# How to open a specific table on startup or connect?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

In my current environment I have a HUGE list of tables to scroll down through and finding that specific table I need to double-click is tedious (almost like trying to find a needle in a haystack).

Is there a way to open a specific table upon connecting to a database?

Alternatively, is there a way to create "shortcuts" (something like "favorites") to certain tables, so that they are easily accessible/findable upon SQL Developer startup?

Comment: Are you aware that if you right-click on the `Tables` node in the Connections view that you can apply filters to search for a particular table or tables?  If so, is that the sort of thing that you're looking for?

Comment: No, I wasn't aware. Thank you so much! To answer your question, I would be very happy to have a shortcuts/favorites feature but in lieu of this, your `Apply Filter...` tip works great.

Comment: Same problem for me. I still can't find how to bookmark table. I found a workaround. In SQL worksheet type 'Select * from myTable'                  Then  hover mouse on myTable  in this text query.                               CTRL + CLICK will open this table in edit mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe it is possible to set up a set of "Favorite" tables.  However, if you right-click on `Tables` in your connection, there is an `Apply Filter` option.  That lets you specify criteria to filter the set of tables that are displayed based on the name of the table or on other attributes like the last DDL time, etc.  That's generally the easiest way to reduce the list to a reasonable number of tables.

Comment: Thanks & accepted (unless someone comes with a trick to create a "Favorites"-like list somewhere at the top or toolbar).

Comment: Thanks, it save a lort of my time, even if this solution cannot replace a Favorite System as we can use it in Oracle Toad :(.  Specially because you cannot manage several filters.  So i will still looking for a better 'favorite solution'